# How to get the xml node based on condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This is my xml

```
DECLARE @XMLValues XML
SET @XMLValues = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENTS name="NYSPIT">
<DOCUMENT ID="140208512T200911101">
<REPEATS>
<REPEAT NAME="EXCEPTIONS">
<ROW>
<FIELD VALUE="09_NYC-3A_2" NAME="PageType"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="KeyWord"/>
<FIELD VALUE="020852009111001.002" NAME="ImageName"/>
<FIELD VALUE="2" NAME="PageNo"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="Qualifier"/>
</ROW>
</REPEAT>
</REPEATS>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT ID="140208512T200911102">
<REPEATS>
<REPEAT NAME="EXCEPTIONS">
<ROW>
<FIELD VALUE="09_NYC-3A_2" NAME="PageType"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="KeyWord"/>
<FIELD VALUE="020852009111001.002" NAME="ImageName"/>
<FIELD VALUE="2" NAME="PageNo"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="Qualifier"/>
</ROW>
</REPEAT>
</REPEATS>
</DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
```

and i need to retrieve the XML node for ID - 140208512T200911101 alone. i cant able to get the information using various methods, still didnt get the correct one.

my desired result should be like this :

```
<DOCUMENT ID="140208512T200911101">
<REPEATS>
<REPEAT NAME="EXCEPTIONS">
<ROW>
<FIELD VALUE="09_NYC-3A_2" NAME="PageType"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="KeyWord"/>
<FIELD VALUE="020852009111001.002" NAME="ImageName"/>
<FIELD VALUE="2" NAME="PageNo"/>
<FIELD VALUE="" NAME="Qualifier"/>
</ROW>
</REPEAT>
</REPEATS>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Please help on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @XMLValues.query('/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT[@ID = "140208512T200911101"]')
```

Result

```
<DOCUMENT ID="140208512T200911101">
  <REPEATS>
    <REPEAT NAME="EXCEPTIONS">
      <ROW>
        <FIELD VALUE="09_NYC-3A_2" NAME="PageType" />
        <FIELD VALUE="" NAME="KeyWord" />
        <FIELD VALUE="020852009111001.002" NAME="ImageName" />
        <FIELD VALUE="2" NAME="PageNo" />
        <FIELD VALUE="" NAME="Qualifier" />
      </ROW>
    </REPEAT>
  </REPEATS>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support and it is working fine, for getting the @ID value dynamically from a variable we need to user like this :

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your support and it is working fine, for getting the @ID value dynamically from a variable we need to user like this :

```
DECLARE @DCN Varchar(50)
SET @DCN = '140208512T200911101'
select @XMLValues.query('/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT[@ID = sql:variable("@DCN")]')
```